# Translate standard language text in ABAP

Tags: abap

The standard environment is in spanish, but i need to show the error message in english.

The Variable is in the catch and is called **text**.

```
TRY.
 INSERT zmxgaspayoclick FROM TABLE it_pagos.  
CATCH cx_sy_open_sql_db INTO oref.
*text = oref->get_text( ).   
ENDTRY.
```

Is there a command or something to do that?

Note: It is a WebService.
Regards.

Comment: Why isn't the user logged in using the appropriate locale?

Comment: It is webservice.

Comment: ...so? You should be able to specify the locale nonetheless...

Comment: Why downvote? It was for specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `SET LOCALE` should work here, see [SAP help](https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abapset_locale.htm). You would need to call this before the `TRY` block.